# Symfony2 installing in a sub-directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony

I know this question has been asked before, but for some reason, it's not working for me.

I'm trying to install symfony2 in a subfolder (IE: http://www.mydomain.com/myapp), however, I'm running into several issues:

It looks like I have to modify ALL of my routes to point to this subpath, IE:

```
fos_user_group:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/group.xml"
    prefix: /myapp/group
```

..which does do the job for routing.

HOWEVER, no matter what, even though in the symfony docs, it states that assetic will determine the correct path(http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#linking-to-assets), it is still attempting to locate assets from the root domain, IE:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/bundles/acmedemobundle/js/script.js
```

I have looked in basically every link on google for related issues, I've tried `RewriteBase /myapp`, `RewriteBase /myapp/web`, but all to no avail.

Can anyone help me out here?  This seems insane that it is this difficult to properly route my URLs and assets to the subfolder.  For portability sake (even if the asset issue is somehow resolved), shouldn't there be a way to do this WITHOUT modifying all of my routes?

On a side note, I haven't yet attempted to try this on a unix server.  Currently all testing is being done on wampserver.

Comment: Were you able to find out how to get it to work without setting all of the routes with a prefix?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the base url in the router object, maybe that will fix your problem?

```
$this->getContainer()->get('router')->getContext()->setBaseUrl('/myapp');
```

If you do that you should not have to prefix all your routes with the name of the subdirectory.

Comment: The routing isn't really the issue.  If I must set a prefix in my routing, I will (though it's not optimal).  The issue is mainly the assets, and the fact for portability sake, I have all of these subdirectory references all over my application.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is still and issue for you but it may help someone else. I believe that you should alter your config.yml or config_dev.yml (depending on environment)

For the assets set this (see the "templating" section):

```
framework:
router:
    resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing_dev.yml"
    strict_requirements: true
profiler: { only_exceptions: false }
#set default asset root
templating:
    assets_base_urls: 
        http: [ /path/to/web ]
        ssl:  [ /path/to/web ]
```

Where /path/to/web is the parent folder of the bundle folder.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this on a local environment was adding the following code in `app/config/config.yml`

```
framework:
    templating:
        assets_base_urls:
            http: "http://localhost/symfony_folder/"
            ssl: "http://localhost/symfony_folder/"
```